# Fast API+Uvicornの環境をPyInstallerでビルドしたとき、console=Falseとするとエラーが発生してしまう

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fastapi

自己解決した問題ですが、参考のため投稿します。

## 現象

FastAPI+Uvicornを使用したアプリケーションをPyInstallerでビルドします。
デバッグのため、PyInstallerでビルドしたバイナリにおいて、console=Trueとしてログ出力を見ながら、実行状況を確認していました。
テストをパスして、本番リリースが近づいたので、console=Falseにして、PyInstallerでビルドしたところ以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
File "logging\config.py", line 543, in configure
  File "logging\config.py", line 655, in configure_formatter
  File "logging\config.py", line 474, in configure_custom
  File "uvicorn\logging.py", line 47, in __init__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
  File "_app.py", line 75, in run
  File "_app.py", line 51, in __init__
  File "uvicorn\config.py", line 299, in __init__
  File "uvicorn\config.py", line 407, in configure_logging
  File "logging\config.py", line 809, in dictConfig
  File "logging\config.py", line 546, in configure
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'default'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_app.py", line 120, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 49, in _freeze_support
  File "multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 330, in _bootstrap
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

### 参考記事

似たような問題として、以下の記事がありますが、対策しても現象が変わりません。
場合によっては、以下の記事内容も対応が必要です。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281002/pyinstaller-compiled-uvicorn-server-does-not-start-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 結論

FastAPIオブジェクト宣言前に以下の一文を入れてください。
consoleオプションによりエラー有無が変わることから、FastAPIが標準出力しようとすることが問題でした。

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

## サンプルコード

サンプルコードはフォルダ構成に注意してください。
spec,PS1ファイルは以下のフォルダツリーを前提としています。

```
(project folder)
+---ENV (venvで作成した仮想環境フォルダ)
|
\---tests
   \---pyinstaller_fastAPI
      | _app.py
      | app_release.spec
      | pyinstaller_fastAPI.ps1
      \---app (PyInstaller出力フォルダ)
          +---build
          +---dist
```

### Pythonスクリプト

```py
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, set_start_method, Process
from multiprocessing import Queue as MP_Queue

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

import pathlib
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread
import time
import tkinter as tk
from uvicorn import Config, Server


class ApiResult(BaseModel):
    status: str
    result: dict
    error: dict


sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

api_port = 8080

TERMINATE_SERVER = 'TERMINATE_SERVER'

api_title = 'test Pyinstaller & fast FPI'
api_version = '0.0'

app = FastAPI(
    title=api_title,
    description=api_title,
    version=api_version
)


@app.get(f"/test")
def read_api_root():
    result = ApiResult(
        status='SUCCESS',
        result={'Welcome': api_title, 'version': api_version},
        error={}
    )
    return result.dict()


class web_server_thread:
    def __init__(
            self, web_app, host: str, port: int, reload: bool = False):
        self.config = Config(
            app=web_app,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            reload=reload,
            # log_level="warning",
        )
        self.server = Server(self.config)
        self.server.install_signal_handlers = lambda: None
        self.proc = None

    def start(self):
        self.th = Thread(name="WebServer Thread", target=self.server.run)
        self.th.setDaemon(True)
        self.th.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.th:
            self.th.join(0.25)


class ApiServer():
    def run(self,
            recv_queue, host: str = '127.0.0.1', port: int = 8080):
        self.instThread = web_server_thread(
            app, host=host, port=port)
        self.instThread.start()

        isLoop = True

        while (isLoop):
            time.sleep(0.2)

            while (not recv_queue.empty()):
                item = recv_queue.get()
                if item == TERMINATE_SERVER:
                    self.instThread.stop()
                    isLoop = False

        return


class _DebugDialog():
    def __init__(self, send_queue):
        self.isLoop = True
        self.after_interval = 200

        self.send_queue = send_queue

        self.dialog = tk.Tk()
        self.dialog.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self.dialog.after(self.after_interval, self.loop)
        self.dialog.mainloop()

        return

    def quit(self):
        self.isLoop = False
        self.send_queue.put(TERMINATE_SERVER)
        self.dialog.destroy()
        return

    def loop(self):
        if self.isLoop:
            self.dialog.after(self.after_interval, self.loop)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')

    send_queue = MP_Queue()

    instServer = ApiServer()

    instProcess = Process(
        name='FastAPI Server',
        target=instServer.run,
        args=(send_queue, ),
        kwargs={
            'port': api_port
        }
    )
    instProcess.daemon = True
    instProcess.start()

    _DebugDialog(send_queue)
```

### specファイル

```py
# -*- mode: python -*-
import os
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

current_dir = os.getcwd()
work_dir = current_dir
source_dir = current_dir +'\\tests\\pyinstaller_fastAPI'

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('uvicorn')

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    [source_dir+'\\_app.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False
    )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
options = [('--uac-admin', None, 'OPTION')]

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          options,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='pyinstaller_fastAPI',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='pyinstaller_fastAPI')
```

### PowerShellスクリプト

```
# ターミナルのカレントディレクトリを示す

$PS_FILE_PATH = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$PS_FILE_DIR = Split-Path $PS_FILE_PATH -Parent
$_FILE_NAME_ = Split-Path $PS_FILE_PATH -Leaf

$WORK_DIR = Split-Path $PS_FILE_DIR -Parent
$WORK_DIR = Split-Path $WORK_DIR -Parent
Set-Location -Path $WORK_DIR

$CURRENT_DIR = Convert-Path .
$CURRENT_DIR = Split-Path $CURRENT_DIR -Parent

$PROJECT_NAME = "Test_PyInstaller"
$PYTHON_PATH = $WORK_DIR + '\ENV\Scripts\python.exe'
$PYINSTALL_DIR = $WORK_DIR + '\tests\pyinstaller_fastAPI'
$DIST_PATH = $PYINSTALL_DIR + '\app\dist'
$BUILD_PATH = $PYINSTALL_DIR + '\app\build'
$PROJECT_PATH = $DIST_PATH + '\' + $PROJECT_NAME
$RET_CODE = 0

$LOG_FILE_NAME = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$_FILE_NAME_")
$LOG_FILE_PATH = $PS_FILE_DIR + '\' + $LOG_FILE_NAME + '.log'

Start-Transcript $LOG_FILE_PATH

write-host "実行ファイル名:" $PS_FILE_PATH

write-host "カレントディレクトリ：" $CURRENT_DIR
write-host "作業ディレクトリ：" $WORK_DIR

write-host -NoNewline "プロジェクト名：" $PROJECT_NAME
write-host "■スタンドアローンアプリを生成します。"

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
    Remove-Item -Path $DIST_PATH -Recurse -Force
    write-host -NoNewline "ディレクトリを削除しました。：" $DIST_PATH
}
catch {
    write-host -NoNewline "削除ディレクトリが見つかりません。：" $DIST_PATH
}

try {
    Remove-Item -Path $BUILD_PATH -Recurse -Force
    write-host -NoNewline "ディレクトリを削除しました。：" $BUILD_PATH
}
catch {
    write-host -NoNewline "削除ディレクトリが見つかりません。："
    write-host $BUILD_PATH
}

#スタンドアローン実行形式のビルド
write-host "■スタンドアローン実行形式のビルドを開始します。"
$PYINSTALL = $PYTHON_PATH + " -m PyInstaller $PYINSTALL_DIR\app_release.spec --distpath $DIST_PATH --workpath $BUILD_PATH "
Invoke-Expression $PYINSTALL
write-host "■スタンドアローン実行形式のビルドが完了しました。"

write-host "何かキーを押してください。"
[Console]::ReadKey($true) | Out-Null

write-host "終了します。"
Stop-Transcript

exit $RET_CODE
```